Eclipse does not open after it is installed
So basically I installed the latest version of eclipse (The "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" specifically) on Windows 10
It only opens once from the installer. From that it runs fine, I even made a working program on it.
However, once I close it does not open again
All that happens when I try to open it is the little loading window that says eclipse pops up for a second and then closes
I checked task manager and there's nothing about eclipse before or after I try to launch it
After everything I've tried it still only works once from the installer immediately after I install it, and I'd rather not have to reinstall it every time I try to launch it
I tried restarting the computer and reinstalling it a few times and choosing some different options with each attempt but still the same thing happens
I also updated my version of the JDK
I even gave up at one point and tried to install it on another computer which has Windows 11 and the exact same thing happens. Is it possible that there is a conflict with another application I have?
I have even followed tutorials on how to install it properly but it still refuses to work. I am clearly doing something wrong, since it does not work on either computer, but I just do not understand.
I have spent about 2 days trying to figure this out now and I have not come up with anything
Any help or suggestions would be hugely appreciated!

(edit)
The version of eclipse I am trying to use is the Java 2024-03 (4.31) version. (from https://eclipseide.org/)
Here is a screenshot I got of the window that pops up:
Eclipse IDE 2024 03

If there is anything I did not include or clarify well enough please let me know, thanks!


most probably this link will help you..Troubleshooting. Please let us know

"latest" is not a proper version number. Which way did you install it (using a ZIP archive or the Eclipse Installer)? Please share the download link? "I also updated my version of the JDK" - it is highly recommended to use the Java that is shipped as part of Eclipse (only when using the Eclipse Installer, you can choose a Java installed on your system, which is not recommended). When you start Eclipse from the command line, what will be printed?

@vik You are referring to a question where the answer with the most votes is to delete files, which can wreck your workspace, cause data loss and cause problems that may not be immediately noticed. I've always wondered why people get themselves into trouble by deleting files they don't know about.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you add a screenshot of the window that does pop up? Where did you install it?

@vik Thank you for the suggestion. I could not find any errors in the event viewer for some reason. Also I tried removing the configurations and the plugins folder from the workspace which did not work either. And I tried using the alternative method of launching it through the command prompt that they suggested and that had the same issue.

@howlger Sorry that I did not specify. I installed it from "https://eclipseide.org/" and the version I installed is the 2024-03 (4.31) version.   Also I initially used the java that was part of eclipse but I decided to try using the other one as well in an attempt to fix the problem.  Also from the command line nothing is printed out with the different methods of launching it. I get the same window that disappears after a second

@nitind I just added the screenshot (it took me a handful of tries to time it right as it only shows up really quickly haha)

Anything in the .log file in that .metadata folder (which you should rarely ever remove the contents of)?

@nitind Oh okay, this says it's from yesterday when I last downloaded it and it last worked: https://prnt.sc/agnh3ZRNhLLk  Would the home variable not being set be the problem here? I'm not sure what I should set it to then if it's by default going to use the user file (also I have no idea why it would work perfectly fine only once when downloading it)

I finally got it working! Thank you all for taking the time to look into this with me. I ended up reinstalling it again and choosing one of the more recent versions of Java that came as a part of Eclipse (version 22 rather than 17) instead of the more recent version I installed separately, and now I am able to open Eclipse even after I close it the first time. Thanks!

Actually apparently I was not using the version that was shipped with Eclipse to begin with at all. I went back and downloaded Eclipse with the other versions of Java that were shipped together with it just to make sure and I discovered that it was actually my mistake the whole time. Thank you @howlger for the solution! And thank you everyone else as well!
